# Вывод свободных номеров

Tags: mysql, sql

Что нужно дописать чтобы выводилось правильно? Выводит, что номер свободен. В БД на эту дату номер забронирован.

```
SELECT DISTINCT room.id_room,room.adres,room.price FROM room JOIN reserve ON room.id_room=reserve.id_room 
    WHERE  (datearrive < '2020-08-17' OR dateleave >'2020-08-18')
```

[image: Выводит, что номер свободен]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<=`, `>=` ? Не?)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вывести запись о номере, который свободен на определенную дату, то так:

```
SELECT room.id_room,room.adres,room.price FROM room
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reserve 
    WHERE '2020-08-17' BETWEEN reserve.datearrive AND reserve.dateleave
      AND reserve.id_room=room.id_room)
```

А ваш запрос означает: выведи мне все номера, которые бронировались в любые дни, кроме заданного.

Comment: почему id равные? Выводит только одну запись у которой id бронирования и id номера совпадают. Обновил картинку таблицы.

Comment: поправил. Пробуйте

Comment: если не на один день бронировать то так WHERE '2020-08-17' AND '2020-08-20 '?

Comment: WHERE reserve.datearrive <= '2020-08-20' AND reserve.dateleave >= '2020-08-17'